How to ensure that the computer doesn't beep when put in sleep mode?
Putting this computer into sleep mode gives faint but noticeable beeping sounds synchronized with the blinking light.  System and hardware info:
Device name DESKTOP-GG6AA6L
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz   3.40 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB
Device ID   8dfdsfdsfds5
Product ID  0fdsfsdfsdfsdM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display


Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎2/‎20/‎2024
OS build    19045.4291
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19056.1000.0

What can be done to disable the beeping?
Trying from the cmd prompt as admin:
C:\Windows\system32>
C:\Windows\system32>sc stop beep
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1062:

The service has not been started.


C:\Windows\system32>
C:\Windows\system32>sc config beep start=disabled
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Windows\system32>



Command Prompt (Admin):

sc stop beep
sc config beep start=disabled


Registry Editor:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Sound
Find the Beep entry in the right pane
change the value data to No.

Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.
To Restore default:
sc config beep start=auto, or change registry value to Yes.

trying now, thanks.

This will disable the beep everywhere. You should add to your post what this will do, because I would definitely not want the beep to be gone everywhere. Its like saying: I have a door, but my key doesn't work on the lock, and your solution is: Remove the door entirely. I'm giving a -1 on this answer for that reason.

it didn't stop the beeping for me.  Speaking for myself, I don't mind if the beep is disabled everywhere.  I'll try again, running the cmd as admin, but looking for alternate solutions before firing up `regedit.
